# height:100% works in Chrome but not in Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, flexbox

I have made a [splitter](https://plnkr.co/edit/57gkUC08wVShhR0jSF6s?p=preview) which works perfectly in Chrome.

However, it does not work in Safari. But if we change the height in `.handle-inner` from `100%` to `400px`, we will observe that the splitter (from the top down to `400px`) becomes draggable. That means it is `height:100%` which did not work in Safari.

Does anyone know how to amend the code to make the splitter work in both Chrome and Safari?

**Edit 1:**

I made a more complex example which has similar structure as my real program. In my real program, I do not fix the height as `500px`, I use the whole screen, and don't want to exceed it. Here is the [splitter](https://plnkr.co/edit/iub4CUuZSGkwDBLwJMzP?p=preview) which works perfectly in Chrome, but `height:100%` does not work in Safari.

Here is the [version](https://plnkr.co/edit/GdAewaF2olVplcYn5EEs?p=preview) with `height: 100vh`. We could see the height is too much in both Chrome and Safari. However, we do NOT know how to set `max-height`.

Comment: You are required to give an example of the markup showing the problem here, not a third party web site that can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your flex container (`.flex-box`) has a defined `height` of 500px.

Your splitter (`.handle-inner`) has a defined `height` of 100%.

However, `.handle`, which exists between them, does not have a defined height. Safari sees this as a missing link, which it considers a violation of the [**spec**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-height-property), which essentially says:

*The parent of an element with a percentage height must have a defined height and it must be with the `height` property. Otherwise, the element with a percentage height must default to `height: auto` (content height).*

Therefore, you need to add `height: 100%` to `.handle`.

---

Also, in your `body` element, you not only have your `.flex-box` element, but you also have a `nav` element with `height: 250px`. Depending on how a browser handles the overflow (250px + 100%), this may cause your splitter element to disappear off-screen, which is happening in Safari.

To avoid that problem, make these adjustments to your code:

```
 * { box-sizing: border-box; }   /* include borders and padding in width
                                    and height calculations */

 .flex-box { height: calc(100% - 250px); } /* compensate for nav height */
```

[**revised demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/nt8wqyfxkk1yd24y8sYm?p=preview)

---

Also, being that `body` is a column-direction flex container, you can also use flex properties (such as `flex: 1` on `.flex-box`) to consume remaining space. You may not even need percentage heights. See my answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33644245/3597276) for details.

[**revised demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ge2gEKH3crXpTwOD2qQR?p=preview)

Comment: Great, it works... Besides, if we add `margin-right: -5px` to `.handle-inner`, it will make the splitter easier to drag. Additionally, in my real program, `height: 100%` in `body` is better than `height: 100vh` (which makes the height of the whole thing longer than my screen). Thank you...

Comment: This saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your height in .handle-inner from 100% to 100vh. Set it up like this with a fall back:

```
.handle-inner {
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Edit: Replace your CSS with this

```
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.flex-box .col {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  flex: 1;
}
.handle {
  width: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
  transition: all ease-in 0.1s;
}
.draggable {
  background: grey;
}

.handle {
  width: 0.0000001px;
  transition: all ease-in 0.1s;
  z-index: 999;
  background: grey;
}

.handle-inner {
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

If you are experiencing overflow, like you stated. Try a height/max-height property.

Comment: after adding `height: 100vh`, you will see even the splitter below out of the box becomes draggable... it is too long...

Comment: I see you removed your Plunker link. I am not experiencing that. I have the link open in both Chrome and Safari. With the vh unit on the height, they are both performing exactly the same

Comment: I did NOT removed my plunker link, and the link you put does not contain `height: 100vh`.

Comment: I see that now. My mistake. I was looking for a run code snippet button. See my edit above.

Comment: Can you make a plunker with your code, I have tested, and it did not work as I stated...

Comment: I have tested this in both Chrome and Safari http://plnkr.co/edit/2768iyLhtAfsQkRHN7v0

Comment: With your plunker, as I said, "the splitter below out of the box becomes draggable... it is too long..."

Comment: A screen shot would be helpful. Which version of Safari are you running?

Comment: Screenshots don't catch the shape of the cursor. I use `Chrome 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)` and `Safari Version 10.0.3 (12602.4.8)`. Just put your cursor over the splitter, then move down, down and out of the box, you will see it is still draggable over the hidden handle-inner...

Comment: Alright, that last bit of additional information helped. I've added a max-height prop after the 100vh prop. This is now consistent between Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Thanks for this. But in some cases, we don't want to set a fixed value as `max-height`. I make a more complex (and real) example. Please see my edit.

Comment: Well, i agree that your fix works for my initial request. But I have a feeling that `height: 100vh; max-height: 500px` is a hack. I would prefer to understand where is the bug and have a more thorough solution. Let us wait a little bit, and see if there are other propositions, I may come back to your answer later...

Comment: I added `Edit 1`, but I didn't change my original post. I can wait a little bit, and don't have to accept an answer immediately.